# Loop through a string from file and turn values into two seperate arrays

Tags: php

Need a quick and easy way to turn a file, into a string
I then need to turn the file into two seperate arrays called $username and $password

File Format:

```
user1:pass1
user2:pass2
user3:pass3
```

etc.
I need the arrays to come out as

```
$username[0] = "user1";
$password[0] = "pass1";

$username[1] = "user2";
$password[1] = "pass2";
```

etc

I have already read the file like this:

```
$file = file_get_contents("accounts.txt");
```

Comment: Can you show us the fruits of your 6 hours of work, you haven't shown any code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array should look like this instead

```
$file = file("log.txt");
$users = array();
foreach ( $file as $line ) {
    list($u, $p) = explode(':', $line);
    $users[] = array("user" => trim($u),"password" => trim($p));
}

var_dump($users);
```

Output

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'user' => string 'user1' (length=5)
      'password' => string 'pass1' (length=5)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'user' => string 'user2' (length=5)
      'password' => string 'pass2' (length=5)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'user' => string 'user3' (length=5)
      'password' => string 'pass3' (length=5)
```

Answer (score 2):

Read on [explode()](http://php.net/explode). However, please note that when your password (or username) contains a colon, this won't work. You might also want to [encrypt your password](http://php.net/md5), and also consider using [salts in encrypting passwords](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Internet/Web_Development/A_4355-Salting-Password-Hashes.html).

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents("accounts.txt");
$file = explode("\n",$file);
$username = array();
$password = array();
foreach ($file as $line) {
    $line = explode(':',trim($line)); // trim removes \r if accounts.txt is using a Windows file format (\r\n)
    $username[] = $line[0];
    $password[] = $line[1];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

do you mean:

```
$content = file("config.txt");
$username = array();
$password = array();

foreach($content as $con) {
  list($user, $pass) = explode(":", $con);
  $username[] = $user;
  $password[] = $pass;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$file = "abcde:fghijkl\nmnopq:rstuvwxyz\nABCDE:FGHIJKL\n";

$reg="/([A-Za-z]{5}):([A-Za-z]+\\n)/i";

preg_match_all($reg,$file,$res);

for($i=0;$i<count($res[0]);$i++){
    echo 'usename is '.$res[1][$i].'====='.'passwd is '. $res[2][$i]."<br />";
}

?>
```

Comment: You need to provide an example

Answer (score 0):

Or you can find the split the string by finding the index of the `:`:

```
<?php
//what you would really do
//$file = file_get_contents("accounts.txt");
//just for example
$file = "abcde:fghijkl\nmnopq:rstuvwxyz\nABCDE:FGHIJKL";
$e = explode("\n", $file);
$username = array();
$password = array();
foreach($e as $line) {
    $username[] = substr($line, 0, strpos($line, ':'));
    $password[] = substr($line, strpos($line, ':') + 1);
}
foreach($username as $u) {
    echo $u."\n";
}
foreach($password as $p) {
    echo $p."\n";
}
?>
```

Output

```
abcde
mnopq
ABCDE
fghijkl
rstuvwxyz
FGHIJKL
```